# Varying Stacked Color by Contrast in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a larger data set similar to the following:

```
example = data.frame(
  person = c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3),
  score =  c(5,1,2, 3,5,1, 1,2,2),
  round =  c(1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3)
)
```

I'm trying to plot it so that each individual has their own color and ever bar in the stack builds up like a gradient. The closest I've managed to get was by allowing the `alpha` to vary by round:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = example,
       aes(x = reorder(person, score),
           y = score,
           fill = factor(person),
           alpha = as.integer(round))) + 
  geom_col()
```

How would one go about varying the colors by contrast instead to create a proper gradient?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

```
ggplot(data = example, aes(x = reorder(person, score), y = score, 
  fill = interaction(person, as.integer(round)))) + geom_col()
```

And then define color values with `scale_fill_manual` to define gradients.

**EDIT**

For the simple example:

```
colornames = sort(levels(interaction(example$person, as.integer(example$round))))
colors = c(
  paste0("red", 1:3),
  paste0("green", 1:3),
  paste0("blue", 1:3)
)

ggplot(data = example, aes(x = reorder(person, score), y = score, 
  fill = interaction(person, as.integer(round)))) + geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = setNames(colors, colornames))
```

If you have lots of persons or rounds, you will probably want to use `colorRamp` or `rgb` to set up colors programmatically.

**EDIT 2**

Or hack it by using semi-transparent white columns:

```
ggplot(data = example, aes(x = reorder(person, score), y = score, fill = factor(person))) + 
  geom_col() + geom_col(aes(alpha = as.integer(round)), fill = "white") +
  scale_alpha(NULL, guide = FALSE, range = c(0, 0.4))
```

Comment: How would one do that? OP has larger dataset, what if it's 100 samples? You recommend to specify color manually?

Comment: You could easily use `colorRamp` to get the gradients and/or use `rgb` to specify colors programmatically... but if OP has a large dataset of 100 people, color is probably not the right way to differentiate.

Comment: Using interactions is a clever idea, but it screws up legends. Ideally, I'd be able to compute the color using both values for each stack instead of a string hack, but I'm not sure how to target them on such a granular level.

Comment: Oh that's very, very clever. That actually feels a lot less hacky than the first way.

Comment: So I've distilled your answer into what seems to be the cleanest solution, but of course, you get the internet points!

Comment: @fny, I guess it seems 'hacky' to me because you are creating color gradients in a way that ggplot cannot represent in the legend. There is probably a way one could customize the legend of the `interaction` approach to display a matrix of colors with "person" on one axis and "round" on the other, but it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here (as inspired by @mikeck) is to create solid color bars underneath the original transparency:

```
ggplot(data = example, aes(x = reorder(person, score), y = score)) + 
  # Base bar color (black is another good color to try)
  geom_col(fill = "white") +
  # Overlay with the colored transparency
  geom_col(aes(fill = factor(person), alpha = round))
```